# how I catch the value not the element itself?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx, react-testing-library

expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality

```
Expected: "Yes"
Received: <span data-testid="write-protected-value">Yes</span>

  236 |                 const ssdEnabled = screen.getByTestId('ssd-enabled-value')
  237 |
> 238 |                 expect(writeProtected).toEqual('Yes')
```

Comment: You can create two span, and render depending on your needs, them `find` (and not `get`) which one is present

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're using the Testing Library (because of `screen.getByTestId()`), so if it's correct, try using `.toHaveTextContent` matcher instead of `.toEqual`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `textContent` or the [getNodeText](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-custom-queries/#getnodetext) helper

```js
const ssdEnabled = screen.getByTestId('ssd-enabled-value')
expect(writeProtected.textContent).toEqual('Yes')

OR

const text = getNodeText(screen.getByTestId('ssd-enabled-value'))
expect(text).toBe('Yes') // no need for `toEqual` if it's not an object
```